# Ставится ли запятая перед И?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, и

После школы не пошла учиться, уехала в другую страну, и начала работать за границей.

Comment: После школы уехать не к подруге, а в другую страну, — такое трудно представить. Разговорное «после школы» надо убрать: «После окончания школы не продолжила обучение».

Answer (score 5):

Запятая перед ***и*** не нужна; союз соединяет однородные сказуемые ***не пошла учиться***, ***уехала***, ***начала работать***, относящиеся к одному подразумеваемому подлежащему (***я***, ***она***).

*После школы не пошла учиться, уехала в другую страну и начала работать за границей.*

[**Однородные члены предложения, соединенные неповторяющимися союзами**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=100)

> Между однородными членами предложения, связанными одиночными соединительными союзами ***и***, ***да*** (в значении ***и***), ***да и***, запятая не ставится: *Часовой дошёл до противоположного угла и повернул обратно* (Ф.).

В Вашем предложении, на мой взгляд, избыточно выглядит ***за границей***, поскольку и так говорится о том, что человек уехал в другую страну.

*После школы не пошла учиться, уехала в другую страну и начала работать.*